# Detect if some other is app installed on iOS device

Tags: ios

I was playing Epoch 2, and after I had installed Epoch 1, Epoch 2 said something like "okay, I see Epoch 1, here are free weapons for you".

How can I do something like this -- detecting the installation of another app -- and what are the limitations of this mechanism?

Comment: Perhaps Epoch detected it via your account and had the information there?

Comment: @mattkc7 thats mean epoch do that on self server somewhere, not at iOS device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app can register custom URL handlers so that the system can direct certain type of requests directly to them.

A common example would be something like

```
appname://
```

or if an app has an associated facebook app it will usually handle facebook redirects to itself with its facebook app id which would look like

`fb37238917293124://` (where the numbers are just the app ID)

Knowing an app's URL scheme will allow you to see if the app is installed on a given device by invoking the `UIApplication`s `canOpenURL` method.

It would look like this:

```
BOOL twitterInstalled = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://"]];
```

Comment: Thank so much! For example, `twitterInstalled` will be YES if twitter app was killed by user?

Comment: And about this URLs, they are public for (popular) apps?

Comment: They're not always public, I could see where some devs would want to have URL functionality for non-public usage, (ie generating "deep application links") not necessarily to have a third party communicate. Also, not all applications will have them so you will be out of luck finding every installed app.

Comment: Thanks, @JustinAmberson! Thats what i was searching for.

Comment: If you can get ahold of the IPA for an app you can extract it and get any custom URL schemes out of its plist file. They will be in the `CFBundleURLTypes` key, within `CFBundleURLSchemes`. Also, to test any custom schemes manually you can just paste them into the safari address bar on your phone and see if you get redirected into the app. For example, typing in `twitter://` into safari should redirect you into the Twitter app.

Comment: Can you post where and how should i add this URL into my app? @Dima

Comment: Do you mean registering your own custom URL scheme?

Comment: Refer to "Register Custom URL Schemes" in the [iOS Programming docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW20)

Comment: Does this still work? I heard Apple made it so I can't just check all the different URLs.

Comment: It still works but you'll need to add `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` to your plist. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl)